# Address issue for Transfer type Shipments

Tags: acumatica

We observed slightly different behavior in SHIP TO ADDRESS of Shipment screen. We have created Transfer type sales order, while creating sales order we have overridden the SHIP TO ADDRESS in Sales Order, then created shipment, now in shipment screen, when we uncheck the "Override Address" checkbox, the address are changing to some default address.

We are using Acumatica 2020R2, build 20.208.0031, without any customizations. Is this default behavior of Acumatica ?

See the below screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you uncheck the override address button it will use the default address for that customer/location combination.

If you need to use a different address you tick the override address button to enter in the address. Once you untick that override address box it will revert to the defaulted address.